# stuck on eloquent javascript excercise 5.2 (make a loop)

Tags: javascript

I've been trying this excercise for hours and I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong.

here's my code.

```
function loop(number, test, action1, action2){
    while(test){
        action2(number);
        action1; 
    }
}

loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
// → 3
// → 2
// → 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything passed to `loop` (except for `number`) is a *function* - you need to invoke all of those functions inside the loop, and reassign `number` to the result of calling `action1`:

```js
function loop(number, test, action1, action2){    
    while(test(number)){
        action2(number);
        number = action1(number);
    }
}

loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
```

Also, you might rename the variables to make each `action` more descriptive - currently, `action1` and `action2` don't seem to be very informative:

```js
function loop(initialNumber, testFn, finalFn, loopBodyFn) {
  let number = initialNumber;
  while (testFn(number)) {
    loopBodyFn(number);
    number = finalFn(number);
  }
}

loop(3, n => n > 0, n => n - 1, console.log);
```